# Disabling "expression expected" from PhpStorm 10

Tags: reactjs, ide, phpstorm

I'm doing some react.js in PhpStorm 10 and even though JSX Harmony is enabled as the JavaScript language level, it still gives all sorts of nonsense errors.

So I disabled inspection completely for JavaScript but it still gives errors like "expression expected" or "Expecting newline or semicolon".

How do I get ride of those for JS?

```
    <script type="text/babel">
        var MyComponent = React.createClass({
           render: function () {
               return <div>
               <h1><p>{this.props.text}</p></h1>
               </div>;
           }
        });

        React.render(<div><MyComponent text="text1" />
<MyComponent text="text2" /></div>, document.getElementById('container'));
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: You can start with providing some sample file that has issues + screenshots of what you see there.

Comment: @LazyOne Added an snapshot + code

Comment: So .. what file type is that? It looks like it's inside a `.html` file.

Comment: @LazyOne, It's indeed inside an `html` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment such inline scripts with `type="text/babel"` are not supported -- IDE only recognizes `text/jsx` as type for now.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18276 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Possible workarounds (that I'm aware of):

- change type to `text/jsx` (but then the in-browser babel most likely will not transform it, unless you can configure it somehow)
- keep your JS code in a separate `.jsx` file

---

**UPDATE:** (23/03/2016) The aforementioned ticket is now marked as "Fixed" -- this functionality should be available in next update of 2016.1.

Comment: That sucks, I did vote for that issue though. Hope it gets fixed soon. At the moment the best thing we can do is changing the type to `text/jsx` while working inside editor and changing it back to `text/babel` before running the app.

Comment: You could try with custom Language Injection (similar to what described in this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16444#comment=27-1150207) to force Harmony there, but it did not worked for me (made no difference).